# Sum textboxes to other textbox wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have i wpf form with 3 textboxes there i should write how many tickets, then i want to multiply that number with a value
At the end i have another textbox there i want the sum from the 3 textboxes even if only 1 has value

i have tried this:

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
  textBox3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)).ToString();
 }

 private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
  textBox3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)).ToString();
 }
```

[image]

Cant get it to work
Please help

Comment: Can you give us a better idea of what _Cant get it to work_ means?  I'd start by using `int.TryParse` to do your conversions - doing them one at a time.  That way, when you step through in the debugger you can see what's going on.  Temp variables really don't cost anything; the optimizer will remove them from a release build so they have no impact on performance

Comment: By the way, have you noticed that your code is now readable.  That's because @ash edited your question, formatting your code (likely using the `{}`) to look like `code`.  You should learn to do this.

Comment: I did used this {}
I cant get the sum to being added if only 1 box has value, and i cant get the multiply to work
And if i add 1 in first textbox and 2 in textbox 2 then delete the value in 1 of the boxes, the sum is not being changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a string value to an integer value you may use `int.Parse` method. On the other hand this method (also `Convert.ToInt32`) requires you making sure that string is always in a good format to get converted. If you are not sure and/or you know that the string may be not in correct format, you may use `int.TryParse` method, which returns true/false value, stating whether the convert was succesful also giving out required value if it was successful. If it fails you get default value - 0.

If all textboxes follow same procedure you may create only one `TextChanged` event and bind it to all of them.

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out int gold_ticket_count))
        {
          sum += 120 * gold_ticket_count;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text) && int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out int silver_ticket_count))
        {
          sum += 60 * silver_ticket_count;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text) && int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out int big_show_ticket_count)) 
        {
          sum += 500 * big_show_ticket_count;
        }
        // do smth with the sum...
    }
```

Check if I named textBoxes correctly. It is a good practise to give your controls a meaningful name.

`int.Parse` doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=net-6.0
`int.TryParse` doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

an ugly, quick and dirty but working solution:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int sum1;
    private int sum2;
    private int sum3;
    private int overallSum;

    private void tb1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(tb1.Text, out int tb1Value))
            sum1 = tb1Value *   120;
        else
            sum1 = 0;

        sum_1.Text = sum1.ToString();
        RecalcOverallSum();
    }

    private void tb2_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(tb2.Text, out int tb1Value))
            sum2 = tb1Value * 120;
        else
            sum2 = 0;
     
        sum_2.Text = sum2.ToString();
        RecalcOverallSum();
    }

    private void tb3_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(tb3.Text, out int tb1Value))
            sum3 = tb1Value * 120;
        else
            sum3 = 0;
     
        sum_3.Text = sum3.ToString();
        RecalcOverallSum();
    }

    private void RecalcOverallSum()
    {
        overallSum = sum1 + sum2 + sum3;
        overall_sum.Text = overallSum.ToString();   
    }
}
```

BTW: I would recommend using MVVM instead of code behind, but I know it wasn't the question